# Jest+Enzyme+React TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, jestjs

Hello I am trying to write unit tests for one of my react components and I keep getting the same error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I have 87 passing test and 8 passing test suites, so I do not understand what is the issue with this particular test/component. I am using Jest+Enzyme+React+Typescript. I have tried using enzyme's `Render`, `Shallow` and `Mount` methods, but I still get the same error.

**This is my react component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { 
    Button,
    ButtonStyle,
    Tabs, 
    Tab, 
    StatusType
} from 'oui-react';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../../main/';
import ManageSettingsComponent  from './ManageSettings/ManageSettingsComponent'
import { 
    updateEndpoint
} from '../../Endpoints';

interface DetailViewComponentProps {
    singleEndpoint: any;
    dispatch: Dispatch<{}>;
    updateEndpoint: (endpoint:any) => void;
}

const breadcrumbItems= [
    { label: "Networking", href: "#/a/networking/vcns" }, 
    { label: "CDN", href: "/#/cdn"},
    { label: "Detail View"}
];

const buttonItems= [
    { title: "Apply Tags", class:"", buttonStyle: ButtonStyle.Default },
    { title: "SSL Request", class:"oui-margin-small-left", buttonStyle: ButtonStyle.Default },
    { title: "Activate", class:"oui-margin-small-left", buttonStyle: ButtonStyle.Default },
    { title: "Purge", class:"oui-margin-small-left", buttonStyle: ButtonStyle.Default },
    { title: "Delete", class: "oui-margin-small-left", buttonStyle: ButtonStyle.Danger}
];

const buttons = buttonItems.map( (buttonItem, i) => 
    <span className={buttonItem.class} key={i}>
        <Button
            buttonStyle={buttonItem.buttonStyle} 
        >
            {buttonItem.title}
        </Button>
    </span>
);

export class DetailViewComponent extends React.Component<DetailViewComponentProps, any> { 
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            disabledButtons: true

        };
        this.changeEndpointState = this.changeEndpointState.bind(this);
        this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        const { 
            id, 
            label, 
            hostname,
            origin,
            originType, 
            originValidation, 
            ocid, 
            lastModified, 
            status, description 
        } = this.props.singleEndpoint;

        if (this.props.singleEndpoint) {
            this.setState({ 
                id: id, 
                label: label,
                hostname: hostname, 
                origin: origin,
                originType: originType, 
                originValidation: originValidation,
                ocid: ocid,
                lastModified: lastModified,
                status: status,
                description: description
            })
        }
    }

    changeEndpointState(e: any) {
        const target = e.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({[name]: value, disabledButtons: false});
    }

    handleCancel(e:any){
        const { 
            id, 
            label, 
            hostname, 
            originType, 
            origin,
            originValidation, 
            ocid, 
            lastModified, 
            status, 
            description 
        } = this.props.singleEndpoint;

        this.setState({
            id: id, 
            label: label,
            hostname: hostname, 
            origin: origin,
            originType: originType, 
            originValidation: originValidation,
            ocid: ocid,
            lastModified: lastModified,
            status: status,
            description: description,
            disabledButtons: true
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(endpoint:any){
        this.setState({
            disabledButtons: true
        })
        console.log(endpoint);
        this.props.updateEndpoint(endpoint);
    }

    render(){
        const { 
            id, 
            label, 
            hostname,
            origin: origin, 
            originType, 
            originValidation, 
            ocid, 
            lastModified, 
            status,
            description,
            disabledButtons 
        } = this.state;  
        const { updateEndpoint } = this.props;

        return( 
            <div>   
                <HeaderComponent 
                    pageTitle={this.props.singleEndpoint.label} 
                    showStatus={true}
                    statusType={status == 'Active' ? StatusType.Success : StatusType.Muted}
                    statusText={status}
                    breadcrumbItems={breadcrumbItems}
                />
                <div className="oui-section oui-section-muted oui-section-xsmall">
                    <div className="oui-container">
                        { buttons }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="oui-margin-medium-top oui-container">
                <Tabs>
                    <Tab label="Manage Settings">
                        <ManageSettingsComponent
                            id={id}
                            label= {label}
                            hostname= {hostname}
                            origin =  {origin}
                            originType={originType}
                            originValidation={originValidation}
                            ocid= {ocid}
                            lastModified= {lastModified}
                            status= {status}
                            description= {description} 
                            disabledButtons = {disabledButtons}
                            handleChange={this.changeEndpointState}
                            handleCancel={this.handleCancel}
                            handleSubmit={(endpoint:any) => this.handleSubmit(endpoint)}
                            />
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab label="Reports" />
                    <Tab label="Tags" />
                </Tabs>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default DetailViewComponent;
```

**This is my test file:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DetailViewComponent from '../components/DetailViewComponent';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../../main/';
import ManageSettingsComponent  from '../components/ManageSettings/ManageSettingsComponent'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { 
    Button,
    ButtonStyle,
    Tabs, 
    Tab, 
    StatusType
} from 'oui-react';

describe('<DetailViewComponent />', () => {
    let wrapper: any;
    let componentInstance: any;

    let singleEndpoint: {};
    let dispatch: Dispatch<{}>;
    let updateEndpoint: () => void;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(
            <DetailViewComponent
                singleEndpoint={singleEndpoint}
                dispatch={dispatch}
                updateEndpoint={updateEndpoint}
            />
        );
        componentInstance = wrapper.instance();
    });

    it('Renders the component', () => {
        expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
    });

});
```

Comment: You don't need to use dive(), DetailViewComponent is not an HOC wrapper

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Even without the dive it stils return undefined

Comment: It seems liike the beforeEach function doesn't get called. Could you please do a `console.log` in it to check that it's being executed?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are passing a value of `undefined` for `singleEndpoint` into your component, causing `componentWillMount()` to fail. Change this line:

```
let singleEndpoint: {};
```

To this:

```
let singleEndpoint = {};
```

And the initial test passes for me.